# LibGDX - How to combine Clicked() method from two click listeners in LibGDX similar to Android?

Tags: java, android, onclick, libgdx, onclicklistener

I want to combine the following two buttons (button1 & button2) into one clicked() method 
which is similar to Android using v.getId().

In LibGDX:

```
button1.addListener(new ClickListener(){
@Override 
public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y){
button1.setText("It was the first button.");                    
}
}); 

button2.addListener(new ClickListener(){
@Override 
public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y){
button2.setText("It was the second button.");                   
}
});
```

In Android:

```
View.OnClickListener action = new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
      switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
          // It was the first button.
          break;
        case R.id.button2:
          // It was the second button.
          break;
      }
  }
}
```

Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the actor (in this case the button) and then do if-else statements to get similar behavior. This click listener can be assigned to each one of your buttons. If you are doing this without storing the buttons in member variables, then you need to declare the buttons first and make them final.

```
ClickListener clickListener = new ClickListener (){
    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y){ 
        Actor actor = event.getListenerActor();
        if (actor == button1) doButton1Action();
        else if (actor == button2) doButton2Action();
        else if (actor == button3) doButton3Action();
    }
}
```

You can also do this with a change listener, and it's slightly simpler.

```
ChangeListener changeListener = new ChangeListener (){
    public void changed (ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
        if (actor == button1) doButton1Action();
        else if (actor == button2) doButton2Action();
        else if (actor == button3) doButton3Action();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's easier to have two ClickListeners but you could add the listener to the View containing the buttons (or Stage or whatever Object the buttons are in) and in the clicked() method check which button the (x,y) coordinates are for like:

```
new ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
        if (x > button1.x && x < button1.x + button1.width
            && y > button1.y && y < button1.y+button1.height) {
            // button 1 was pressed
        }
        // similar for button2
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any ID that I can refer to similar to Android?

Comment: You can use setName(String) to give your buttons unique identifying names and then use getName() to check them. This works for any kind of actor in LibGDX.